# Dropdown is hiding inside flash.swf

Tags: html, flash, drop-down-menu

```
         <table>
         <tr>
         <td>
         <div id="dropdownmenu">
         <a href="#">Red</a>
         <a href="#">Orange</a>   
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")
         </script></td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF; vertical-align:top;">
         <td>  
         <object height="251" width="504">
         <param value="Flash.swf" name="movie">
         <param value="Transparent" name="wmode">
         <embed width="504" height="251" src="Flash.swf"/> //here flash is hiding drop 
         </object>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

Here flash.swf is hiding the dropdownmenu .I want the dropdown outside the flash but it displaying inside the flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the `wmode` parameter in the embed tag:

```
<embed width="504" height="251" src="Flash.swf" wmode="transparent" />
```

The `<param` based `wmode` only targets Internet Explorer